# Binding Visible property of a DataGridColumn in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I cannot bind the Visible property of the WPF datagridtextcolumn to a boolean value.

My binding expression is,

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.IsThisColumnVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Converter={StaticResource vc}}
```

I have checked that the converter works (bool to the visibility enum) and is in scope.

If I use the same expression for the header of the column, the header displays 'false' as expected.

Visible is a dependency property so should be bindable.

Anyone see what Im doing wrong?  Or has anyone else been able to bind to the visible property.

Regards,

Matt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I worked this out.

DataGridCOlumn is not a framework element so the FindAncestor call was failing (DataGridColumn not part of visual tree)

Have to set source property of binding expression to a staticresource and it works fine.

Comment: Here is the example of using StaticResource proxy to forward DataContext: http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: i am using MVVM and it worked finde with the provided link: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say from so little of your code. What is in Visual Studio's Output window (under Debug)? That will often give you a clue as to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing and found an execellent way to do it in [an article about forwarding datacontext to columns](https://web.archive.org/web/20160227001645/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx).

Comment: Yes. forwarding datacontext is the way to go. Similar but IMHO simpler approach: http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Answer (score 0):

If you can bind from code you can use

```
BindingOperations.SetBinding(DatagridColumInstance,
                             DatagridColum.VisibilityProperty,
                             myNewBindDef);
```