# XAML ListView: header binding not working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I can't make the `{Binding Title}` in the `HeaderTemplate` appear.

This is the class connected to the BindingContext:

```
class SensorGroup
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public IList<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView  Header=""
           ItemsSource="{Binding Sensors}">

  <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"/>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  ...
</ListView>
```

If I replace it with `<Label Text="Some static text"/>`, the text appears.

I have found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654305/wpf-datagridtemplatecolumn-header-binding-not-working), which links to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857780/how-to-hide-wpf-datagrid-columns-depending-on-a-property/6858917). But I could not make it work. I tried:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <Label x:Key="MyTitle"
            Binding="{Title}"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

...

<Grid>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyTitle"/>
</Grid>
```

It gives me an error saying that the binding with `Title` cannot be found.

Comment: Have you set up the DataContext correctly so that it can find the `SensorGroup` class?

Comment: The items of the `ListView ` which are binded to the property `Sensors` are being displayed correctly, so the `BindingContext = new SensorGroup()` (oversimplifying) written in the constructor is working properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds you like just need to do:

```
<ListView  Header="{Binding .}"
           ItemsSource="{Binding Sensors}">
```

That is if your `ContentPage`'s `BindingContext` is set to the `SensorGroup` class.

The above is telling the `ListView.Header` to be bound to what ever the `ContentPage.BindingContext` is set to. That means that the `ListView.HeaderTemplate` controls will also use what ever `ContentPage.BindingContext` is set to.

Let me know if that does not make any sense.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. It seems logical in hindsight, but I think I could have been staring at the code for weeks and I still wouldn't have figured it out by myself... I was following the Xamarin tutorials and they were telling me to set `Header=""` to make the header work (with static text, of course). So stupidly enough, I was following this rule blindly.

Comment: @XavierPeña Happy to help and I did the exact same thing until I finally found someone else's post on it. No point in losing hair without a good reason ;)

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem :) shame Xamarin don't document it really!