# Binding failed for a GridViewColumn Visibility property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Name="lvRegistersConfig" ItemsSource="{Binding registers}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <local:BoolToVisibility x:Key="BTVConverter"/>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <local:GridViewColumnExt Header="Register Name" Width="100" Visibility="{Binding Vis, Converter={StaticResource BTVConverter}}" >
                    <local:GridViewColumnExt.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Visibility="{Binding Vis, Converter={StaticResource BTVConverter}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:GridViewColumnExt.CellTemplate>
                </local:GridViewColumnExt>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

GridViewColumnExt is a class that inherits from GridViewColumn and adds the Visibility property.

My ListView's ItemsSource as you may see, is set to be the registers ObservableCollection. Register class has a property of type bool named Vis. 
It all works fine for the TextBox, but from the GridViewColumnExt don't, i think i cannot reach the collection and bind to the specific object.

I am not sure what's the DataContext for the GridViewColumn, i saw that i cannot set it. 
I need a hint on this, how can my GridViewColumn see the Vis property from the Register object in the registers ObservableCollection ?

Comment: Adding a Visibility binding for an entire column based on a property of an individual item doesn't make any sense.  What if item 1 has Vis = true and item 2 has Vis = false, do you hide the entire column or not?

Comment: @user3910810 if any item exists on that column i will display it. I have my ListView inside an expander and i am checking that on the expanded event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857780/how-to-hide-wpf-datagrid-columns-depending-on-a-property

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the `GridViewColumnExt` control works, but it looks like with your XAML that the `DataContext` is not going to be individual item in the `registers` collection, rather it is the same `DataContext` on which the `registers` collection is declared. So, you're probably not going to be able to control the visibility of the column with the `Register.Vis` property.

If you're looking to put more in your cell template, you could wrap the `TextBlock` in a `Grid` and bind the `Grid.Visibility` property to the `Register.Vis` property.

Does that make sense?