# How do I bind a WPF DataGrid DataColumns visibility to a property on the UserControl's ViewModel?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF DataGrid contained in a UserControl.

**In the ViewModel for the user control I have the following defined:**

```
private Visibility _ColumnVisibility;
public Visibility ColumnVisibility
{
get { return _ColumnVisibility;}
set {this._ColumnVisibility= value;
     OnNotifyPropertyChanged("ColumnVisibility");}
}
```

**My Column definition in XAML looks like this:**

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserCode}"
    Header="UserCode"
    Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=ColumnVisibility}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**I get the following exception at runtime:**

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=ColumnVisibility;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn'
>   (HashCode=21737301); target property is 'Visibility' (type
>   'Visibility')

What is the best way (easiest) way to bind DataGrid column visibility to a property defined in the ViewModel of the containing UserControl?

Comment: Why `RelativeSource` when you want to bind to a property in the view model of the usercontrol?

Comment: Dr.Fre:  So the correct way to bind would be...?

Comment: Did you try this? `Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.ColumnVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>`

Comment: EP: In my case, wouldn't my ancestor be the UserControl (Since it's within the viewmodel that my property is defined within)

Answer (score 1):

I found an elegant solution in SO by **AnjumSKhan** here:
[How to hide wpf datagrid columns depending on a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857780/how-to-hide-wpf-datagrid-columns-depending-on-a-property)

```
<!-- 
AnjumSKhan: I would prefer a more elegant approach which involves using a Freezable.
-->
<Window.Resources>
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame x:Key="FlagKey" Value="{Binding Flag}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```