# WPF Binding with DataContext in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datacontext

I got a WPF DataGrid and in the DataGrid i want to have a column displayed dependent on a property outside of the DataGrid Context (from the ViewModel).

I have the same Property binding outside of the DataGrid for some labels (without the "DataContext." ) and this works fine.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items.View}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   x:Name="Overview" >

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{lex:Loc Value}" Width="Auto" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Overview, Path=DataContext.CharacteristicMeasure.Characteristic.CharacteristicType.IsBool,Converter={StaticResource boolToInv}, ConverterParameter=true}" >
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" />
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"  />
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Somehow this isnt effecting the Visibility property of the DataGridTemplateColumn at all. I dont know why and how to continue.

**UPDATE**

My output windows shows the following error:

```
    System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.CharacteristicMeasure.Characteristic.CharacteristicType.IsBool; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTemplateColumn' (HashCode=15721293); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

**UPDATE 2**

though i got the same Property Binded on another Visibility Property outside of the DataGrid

```
    <DockPanel Visibility="{Binding CharacteristicMeasure.Characteristic.CharacteristicType.IsBool,Converter={StaticResource boolToInv}, ConverterParameter=true}" >...
```

and this works fine.

Comment: Attach your debugger and put a breakpoint in your converter's ConvertTo method. That should verify that your property is wired up correctly and that the converter is converting it to a Visibility enum.

Comment: Converter isnt executed. i get the following output: System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.CharacteristicMeasure.Characteristic.CharacteristicType.IsBool; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTemplateColumn' (HashCode=15721293); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

Comment: Doh! Bitten by this again - DataGridColumn isn't a visual element. possible duplicate of [Binding to Visible property DataGridCOlumn in WPF DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669060/binding-to-visible-property-datagridcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strange as it sounds, the [`DataGridColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class inherits directly from `DependencyObject`, so you can't use bindings on its properties (it has no [`SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598273.aspx) method).

Can't figure out why.

Comment: Thank you. Now i do understand the Problem and already fixed it.
I did bind the Property to the TextBox and display another TextBox with the inverted version of this converter. Thanks